# JAVA/MYSQL Can Java Control The Rows Being Displayed Using SELECT Statement

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql

I have a project that has multiple users. There are two user types the person who orders and the person who bids.

When the PERSONS WHO ORDER post orders. It will reflect to BIDDERS account.
What I want is something like this, when a BIDDER hasn't bid for anything all the available orders for bid will appear to his account.
I have two tables: ORDERS and BIDS

ORDERS TABLE:

```
OrderID|Item    | OrderStatus|
1      |Shoes   | On-Bidding |  
2      |Bag     | On-Bidding |  
3      |Shirt   | On-Bidding |
```

BIDS TABLE:

```
BidID | BidCost | BidStatus |BidderID  |OrderID  |  
  1   | $100    |Waiting    | 2        |2        |  
  2   | $200    |Waiting    | 1        |2        |
```

The table that I want to display using JAVA is like this:

The AVAILABLE FOR BID table that will appear to the user:

For Bidder ID 2(He bids for the bag so the BidCost column will be joined):

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |  
2       |Bag    | $100    |  
1       |Shoes  | NULL    |  
3       |Shirt  | NULL    |
```

For Bidder ID 1 (He also bids for the bad for $200)

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |  
2       |Bag    | $200    |  
1       |Shoes  | NULL    |  
3       |Shirt  | NULL    |
```

For Bidder ID 3(He didn't Bid Anything)

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |  
2       |Bag    | NULL    |  
1       |Shoes  | NULL    |  
3       |Shirt  | NULL    |
```

What I did was just SELECT all with the ON-BIDDING status and JOIN it with the BID Table for the BidCost. But everytime I do that. If someone has already bid for an item and another user has not, the bid cost will not appear to him/her as null. The bid of the other user will be joined. So that user will see the bid of another user.

How can I do this using MySQL and JAVA?

My QUERY:
SELECT * FROM orders T1 INNER JOIN SELECT bidcost FROM bids T2 ON T1.ID= T2.ID WHERE orderstatus=ON-BIDDING

Comment: Show your SQL requests first

Comment: @Pavlo that was just a part of a bigger table. Using that: SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN SELECT bidcost FROM bids

Comment: @Pavlo I am using servlets to JSP to display it. But any explanation about java or mysql will do.

Comment: What about join condition ON T1.ID=T2.T1_ID;

Comment: Looks like your problem in SQL request. Try it in some SQL console.

Comment: @Pavlo Yeah i have that sorry. SELECT * FROM orders T1 INNER JOIN SELECT bidcost FROM bids T2 ON T1.ID= T2.ID WHERE orderstatus=ON-BIDDING. But that's not my problem. It works, but when a BIDDER didn't bid. The bid of other BIDDER will show or joined. I just wanna show NULL when a BIDDER doesn't bid.